# Validate and submit two forms as one jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" name="save" id="btn"> ok </button>

<div id="acc">
    <h3>First header</h3>
    <form name="form1" id="id_form1" method="post">
        <div><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required></div>
    </form>
    <h3>Second header</h3>
    <form name="form2" id="id_form2" method="post">
        <div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" required></div>
    </form>
    <h3>Third header</h3>
    <form name="form3" id="id_form3" method="post">
        <div><input type="text" id="address" name="address" required></div>
        <button type="submit" name="create"> create </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $( "#acc" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false
    });

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $('#id_form1').submit();
    });

    $('#id_form1').validate({
        ignore: "",
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
            alert('ttt');
        },
    });
});
```

Please visit the link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6b0w1y1/4/)

I got there 3 headers (panels). The first two I would like to validate and submit as one after pressing the OK button, but I can't put them into the one form in the html code because of the accordion header `<h3>`. The third panel is just for this example (doesn't need to be coded now), it's separate one. As you noticed the code under the above link works only with one form for validation.

Comment: Can you wrap everything (button and accordion) within a single <form>?

Comment: no, the structure has to be like the example shows (separate button, separate form(s) in third panel or even fourth in future. I may want add extra panel and make validate as one with first two.

Comment: Some of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[javascript]%22submit%20multiple%20forms%22) might help?

Comment: I've been dealing with this for a while and I've already read many of them and still trying do something with it, but with no luck to find good solution for me so far. What I've read so far is that I have to combine two forms or so into one form and submit that form. The problem is how to validate? I'd have to do that before connecting these two forms. I can't even think of any other solution to have accordion and do things as described in example.

Answer (score 1):

Put hidden inputs in one form, and have the `OK` button copy the values from the inputs of the second form to them after validating.

```
<button type="submit" name="save" id="btn"> ok </button>

<div id="acc">
    <h3>First header</h3>
    <form name="form1" id="id_form1" method="post">
        <div><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden_lastname" name="lastname">
    </form>
    <h3>Second header</h3>
    <form name="form2" id="id_form2" method="post">
        <div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" required></div>
    </form>
    <h3>Third header</h3>
    <form name="form3" id="id_form3" method="post">
        <div><input type="text" id="address" name="address" required></div>
        <button type="submit" name="create"> create </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    if ($("#id_form1").valid() && $("#id_form2").valid()) {
        $("#id_form2 input").each(function() {
            $("#id_form1 #hidden_" + this.id).value(this.value);
        });
        $("#id_form1").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems to be the simplest solution in my situation. I want to test this fully but I found out that I don't know how to read the values in php when submitting like this. The button is outside the form so this syntax doesn't work `if (isset($_POST["save"])) {}` How to find out in php that the button was pressed to submit and then read values in this situation?

Comment: Ok, I'll answer my self. First, your code has also a small mistake. The middle line should be: `$("#id_form1 #hidden_" + this.id).val(this.value);` To find the submit button outside the form I assigned its value to a hidden input in that form. Check at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6b0w1y1/6/) (but this is just for view the code because I can't get it work at fiddle with this php line). I'm not sure if this is the best way to look for a submit button, but it works. Anyway, thank you for your post, it gave me some idea about the topic how can be solved. So far it's the best answer.

Comment: You don't really need to look for the submit button, you can use `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Comment: but if I have two or more submit buttons like in the example then I have to know somehow which one was pressed. I think the above code is fine to use if someone has only one form with one submit button.

Comment: That's true. Then you can use additional hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own handler for the submit. In the handler you can validate your data, get the values from the forms (look at jQuery serialize), then use jQuery's post to send the data. Something like this (not real code, but should get you there)

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    if( input1.isValid() && input2.isValid){
        var formInputSerial = $('form').serialize();
        $.post("http://whereToSendData", formInputSerial, callbackFunction(ifNeeded))
    }
}
```

You will have to implement the the validation checks for the input. You may need to add a common to class to the input then use $('.commonClass').serialize(); I'm not sure how the above will work with multiple forms.